# What does $\mathbb{Z}_q^n\times\mathbb{Z}_q$ mean?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

Seen [here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ecpeikert/pubs/lattice-survey.pdf#page=24), what set are you sampling from? I understand $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ however I am having trouble with this. Thanks

Comment: What is your understanding of $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$?  Because it is $\mathbb{Z}_q^n = \mathbb{Z}_q \times \mathbb{Z}_q \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_q$ for $n$ factors, which implies you understand the $\times$.  Which is the confusing part?

Comment: At any rate, it's the set of ordered pairs where the first part is a vector and the second is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_q$

Comment: Thank you. That has completely cleared it up for me.

Comment: they may want to write it with only $2$ commas instead of $n$.

Comment: It is the same as $\mathbb Z_q^{n+1},$ for what it is worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically $\mathbb{Z}^n_q \times \mathbb{Z}_q$ is the same as $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}_q$;
I can see why the author does what he does. It fits the flow of the idea better to say pick $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n_q$ according to the uniform distribution and then pick $a \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ [which may be easier for the reader to picture what is really happening than to say pick $y$ from $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}_q$ according to the uniform distribution and then write $y=(x,a)$--this is technically correct too but may be harder to follow].

The author's notation would make even more sense if e.g., he were picking $x$ from $\mathbb{Z}^n_q$ according to the uniform distrution and then $a$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ according to some distribution that may not be uniform.

Comment: $e$ comes from a non-uniform distribution $\chi$.